# How to select source density of image when using android ui utils

Tags: android, nine-patch

I am generating nine patch images using [android ui utils](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html)
I am not sure of what to select for the source density field.
How do i know the right density to choose?
Is there a way to determine this from my image dimensions?
Thanks

Comment: i have the same question, have you got that?

Comment: The answer below is OK, so i just check the resolution of my image, if necessary, i change it to 320x489 and then select mdpi as my source density. I'm not sure if this is very right or if perhaps there's a better way. But so far i haven't had trouble, yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's source density, like if designer draw for mdpi (for example, screen resolution is 320x480), and give you images in this density, you need choose mdpi.

Also i recommend you [this](http://weblookandfeel.com/downloads/ninepatch-demo.jar) nine patch editor.